# Two problems : this.myMethod is not a function - click event added by addEventListner run more then 20 times when user click

Tags: javascript, timer, vue.js, vuejs2

I trying to make a timer with vue.js, but I have some problems. this is my mtehods section :

```
methods: {         
    saveRunningMethod() {
        var runningData = {
            duration: `${this.hour} : ${this.minute} : ${this.second}`,
            username: this.$store.state.user.username
        }
        this.$store.dispatch('saveRunning' , runningData)
        console.log(runningData);
    },
    startTimer(){     
        this.isTimerStart = true;
        var timer = window.setInterval(() => {

           var e = document.getElementById("stopBtn")
           e.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
               clearInterval(timer) 
               this.isTimerStart = false;
               console.log("lets Save it")
               this.saveRunningMethod()
               });

           if(this.mSecond < 9)
                this.mSecond +=1
            else
                this.mSecond=0

           if(this.mSecond==9)
                this.second +=1                

            if(this.second>59)                   
                this.second=0

            if(this.second==59)
                this.minute +=1

            if(this.minute>59)
                this.minute = 0

            if(this.minute==59)
                this.hour +=1              

    },100);

    }
}
```

Here, my `e.addEventListener("click", function(){` will stop the timer when I click on my stop button, but it seems this methods run multi times, as you can see in this photo, my console.log runs like 33 times! why is that?

[image]

My Other question, is about this line : `this.saveRunningMethod()` I run this method inside my `startTimer()` method but I get `"this.saveRunningMethod() is not a function"` error!

At the end, as you can see I used `setInterval` to make a timer, if you know a better solution I will really appreciate it.

UPDATE : I add my html part

```
<div class="row p-2 m-3 mt-3">
        <div class="col-12 p-0 animated fadeInUp mt-3">
            <p class="text-center">Your last record was : 00:00:00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 p-0 animated fadeInUp mt-3">
            <h1 class="text-center timer">
                {{this.hour}}:{{this.minute}}:{{second}}:{{mSecond}}
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-2 mt-3" v-bind:class="[this.isTimerStart==false ? 'show' : 'hide']">
        <div class="col-12 p-0 animated tada text-center">
            <button class="btn-link timerImg" @click="startTimer()">
                <img class="img-fluid timerImg" src="../../static/timerStart.png" />
                <p>Start</p>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row p-2 mt-3" v-bind:class="[this.isTimerStart ? 'show' : 'hide']">
        <div class="col-12 p-0 animated tada text-center">
            <button id="stopBtn" class="btn-link timerImg">
                <img class="img-fluid timerImg" src="../../static/timerStop.png" />
                <p>Stop</p>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: From your code is not clear, why is timer running mutiple times. Edit question and add HTML part also.

Comment: @WaldemarIce My html part is just one div which show the timer and two buttons, I update the question and add it anyway. thanks.

Comment: One question at a time, please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EmadDehnavi Try, as quick fix, defining start timer as arrow function. Just change first line to this syntax: `startTimer: _=> {`

Comment: @Rob Sorry, Since both was related to same code I just asked them in one question, Noted for next time, thanks.

Comment: @WaldemarIce I used the arrow function, still same.

Comment: @EmadDehnavi You got this error `this.saveRunningMethod() is not a function` with arrow function too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MDN](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setInterval.html), this is what `window.setInterval()` does:

> Calls a function repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

So when your `startTimer()` method is executed, it is adding a `click` event listener to your stop button every 100 milliseconds. So if you load the page and wait 3.3 seconds before clicking the stop button, the `click` event listener will have been added to the button 33 times:

```
var timer = window.setInterval(() => {

    var e = document.getElementById("stopBtn")
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // This code will execute 33 times when the stop button is clicked.
    })
    ...
}, 100)
```

If you load the page and wait 5.4 seconds before clicking the stop button, the `click` event listener will have been added to the button 54 times!

Instead of using `window.setInterval()` you should use `window.setTimeout()`. [According to MDN](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html), this is what it does:

> Executes a code snippet or a function after specified delay.

In other words, `window.setTimeout()` creates a timer that only runs once, after a delay that you specify.

As for the error that `this.saveRunningMethod() is not a function`, your context is changing inside the callback function passed to `addEventListener()`, so the value of `this` becomes the button itself, not your object. In order to avoid this, you can pass an arrow function to `addEventListener()`. This will cause the context to remain unchanged (so inside the arrow function, the value of `this` will remain your object):

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    var e = document.getElementById("stopBtn")
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
        this.isTimerStart = false;
        console.log("lets Save it");
        this.saveRunningMethod();
    });
}, 100)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it explain everything, I guess I need to find another way to create a timer since cannot achive it by setTimeout neither with setInterval. Also adding the arrow function to addEventListener() fixed the issue for my second question.